# Integer promotions in C will downgrade `long int`?

Tags: c

From the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

6.3.1.1

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-ﬁeld), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions.

So this means that if I use a `long int` in an expression it will be downgraded to an `unsigned int`?

Comment: No - because an int can't represent "all possible values" of the long int.

Comment: Well, if `long int` are actually bigger than `int`s, anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit you quoted is restricted by the text above it:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int,or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is
>   converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.
>   These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged
>   by the integer promotions.

In other words, `long int` doesn't get promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

I think "original type" refers to "[...] an integer type (other than int or unsigned int)
whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and
unsigned int", as defined earlier in section 6.3.1.1.2.  But, nice try :)